# How to use Shopify metafields in the theme app block dynamic source settings?

Tags: shopify, liquid

How to use the metafields (or [app.metafields](https://shopify.dev/docs/apps/online-store/theme-app-extensions/extensions-framework#conditional-app-blocks)) in the block settings?

The idea is to save the app.metafield on the app storefront and let merchants use this dynamic source in the theme app settings something like

```
{% schema %}
    {
      "name": "App block",
      "target": "section",
      "available_if": "{{ app.metafields.myapp.global_enable }}",
      "stylesheet": "animate.css",
      "javascript": "app.min.js",
      "settings": [
        {
          "type": "header",
          "content": "App Block"
        },
        {
          "type": "radio",
          "id": "select_me",
          "label": "Select the block",
          "options": "{{ app.metafields.myapp.somelistofdynamicvalues }}"
        }
      ]
    }
    {% endschema %}
```

When I try to push the theme app extension to Shopify it return an error like
`[blocks/conditional-app-block.liquid] Invalid tag 'schema': settings: with id="select_me" options must be an array`

I successfully save the app metafield to store in the JSON or [list.single_line_text_field](https://shopify.dev/docs/apps/custom-data/metafields/types#list-types) but was not successful to use them in the settings.

I also try to simply assign the variable in liquid like `{% assign my_variable = 'some json' %}` but got the same error.

The question was raised after Shopify announced the Assets API shutdown create/delete access.

Comment: Hope to see updates on the topic here or on Shopify side soon

Answer (score -1):

Shopify documents types that support Dynamic Sources here: https://shopify.dev/docs/themes/architecture/settings/dynamic-sources

Unfortunately choice based inputs like `radio` and `select` are not currently supported.

Comment: seems to me the app.metafields does not have any dynamic settings support. What a limited platform